# Populate date Matches in Select2 item in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an issue which I want to populate date that matches data in the select2 multiple let say I have data from database `C,D,E` with dates `['2023-12-01', '2023-12-02', '2023-12-03']` the problem is when I select another item like "b" it will jumble or replace the `E` date and it will turns to blank, All I want is whatever the position of select2 let say `C,D,F`  and then I click "E" then the date that comes from database will retain to their corresponding letters so will insert the "E" automatically between D and F and it is blank since it is new so it will turn to `C,D,E,F`  `['2023-12-01', '2023-12-02',,'2023-12-03']`

can anyone have an idea? any answer will appreciated!

```js
$('#remarks-list').val([3,4,5]).trigger('change');
    let clicked_id = 0;
    let status_val =0;
    let formattedDates = ''
    let employeeList = [];

    let selectedRemarks = [];

    let selectedRemarksOrder = [];
    let remarksDateMap = {};

    $(function () {
       
    $('select').each(function () {
        $(this).select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
        width: 'style',
        placeholder: $(this).attr('placeholder'),
        allowClear: Boolean($(this).data('allow-clear')),
        });
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        let remarks_date = ['2023-12-01', '2023-12-02', '2023-12-03']
        

        $(".remarks-list").on("change", function() {
            $("#dynamic-input-container").empty();
            selectedRemarks = $(this).val();
            
            if (selectedRemarks) {
                selectedRemarksOrder = selectedRemarksOrder.filter(item => selectedRemarks.includes(item));
                selectedRemarksOrder = selectedRemarksOrder.concat(selectedRemarks.filter(item => !selectedRemarksOrder.includes(item)));


                for (var i = 0; i < selectedRemarksOrder.length; i++) {
                    var selectedRemark = selectedRemarksOrder[i];
                    var inputId = "date-remarks-" + selectedRemark;
                    var selectedText = $(this).find('option[value="' + selectedRemark + '"]').text();

                    var inputValue = remarks_date[i] || "";
                    var inputElement = '<label class="form-label">Date for <b>' + selectedText + '</b></label> <input type="date" id="' + inputId + '" name="DateRemarks" class="form-control" value="' + inputValue + '" /><br>';
                    $("#dynamic-input-container").append(inputElement);
                    
                }
            }
        });

        $("#dynamic-input-container").on("change", 'input[type="date"]', function() {
            var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
            var selectedRemark = inputId.replace("date-remarks-", "");
            remarksDateMap[selectedRemark] = $(this).val();
        });



    })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #444444;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}

h3 {
  color: #000000;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- select2 -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- select2-bootstrap4-theme -->
  <link href="https://raw.githack.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme/master/dist/select2-bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- for live demo page -->


    <div class="col-12">
        <label>Let say It just an edit item and this appears and theres data from database which <b>C,D,E</b> and date which is <b>['2023-12-01', '2023-12-02', '2023-12-03']</b></label> <br> <br>
            <select id="remarks-list" name="RemarksList" class="select2 form-select remarks-list" style="width: 100px; height: 200px;" multiple>
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">C</option>
                <option value="4">D</option>
                <option value="5">E</option>

            </select>
        <span id="remarks_error" style="color: red;"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <br>
        <div id="dynamic-input-container"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can anyone have an idea?

Comment: `selectedRemarksOrder = selectedRemarksOrder.sort();`